# How to use a .tff font in a Quarto webpage?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, truetype, quarto

I'm trying to use CaskaydiaCove [Nerd Font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) as my default `monofont`. Yet I can't find any linkable version of it, only the original Cascadia Code on [CDN Fonts](https://www.cdnfonts.com/cascadia-code.font) but it doesn't have the glyphs I want. Is there a way to use the .tff version in a Quarto website?

Comment: I think, this question boils down to how to use a font from local folder as monofont in quarto, right?

Comment: @shafee That would be one solution, I used more general wording in case there's some kind of hosting or something like that, which one could use.